# Need to make an Exception. I want to catch an error when a user Inputs an non numeric value in an array

Tags: exception

Can anyone help me with making an Exception. I want to catch an error when a user Inputs an non numeric value in an array. After it catches the error i would like to ask the user to retry and give their input again, this time being an integer.

Comment: Sorry, this is super broad. Maybe if you add some example code that is not working we can assist.

Comment: In any particular programming language?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming JAVA, 
All you have to do is get the I put as a string, then convert the string to integer by `Integer.parseInt()`.

If the parseInt doesn't throw NumberFormatException, user entered a numeric input, add that to the array,  if not, get an input again

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this in a simple application in order to test your Exception-handling skills, here is a sample code that fills an array with integers and expects int as input. When given another value, the code prompts the user to try again.

```
int[] array = new int[10];

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean shouldAskAgain = true;
int index = 0;
do{
    System.out.println("Enter an integer value for the array");
    try{
        array[index] = sc.nextInt();
        index++;
        if(index == array.length-1)
            shouldAskAgain = false;
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Wrong input. Try again");
        sc.nextLine();
    }
}while(shouldAskAgain);
```